# Template error on Triage

Tags: bug, status-completed, triage

This is the view I've got today on Triage.

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly the same issue as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345598/deleting-comments-causes-layout-to-be-broken-ajax-response-contains-full-page

Comment: Yup, looking into this this is the exact same underlying problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, doesn't seem to be the same issue that you linked, all review sections looks like this, even after refresh (F5) or (CTRL+F5)

Comment: Sure, but that's because review *starts* with an AJAX request to load the next available review item.

Comment: It's working fine now!

Comment: Glad to hear! The devs must've rolled back whatever caused this.

Comment: Looks like all the issues I've seen have been mitigated now.

Comment: I tried to hit the back button on your screenshot...